# PHP script crashes, running out of memory

Tags: php, out-of-memory, centos7

I am having problem with a php script running from Cron (executed by php).

Script runs fine but crashes after using 512 mb, I can not understand why because I have set the script to use much more, and the server can handle it for sure.

The executed php file is located before the web folder (can this cause the problem?).

Php.ini is set to handle 8192M

What am I doing wrong here (this is declared on top of the executed php file)?

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '8191M');
//ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
```

Comment: What is it doing anyway?

Comment: What _exactly_ does _“from Cron (executed by php)”_ mean?

Comment: it will almost certainly depend on what the script is doing - post some code. if it's running on a cron, the old job might not be ending before the new one starts for example

Comment: until you post some code of the script, we've no way to work out what the culprit is for the excessive memory usage

Comment: Sorry for my explanation, the script is executed with "php script.php" Same problem occurs if the script is running from the terminal or from cronjob.

The script is not the problem, no need to show code. The script is a foreach loop going thru a big array and updating stock information.

The script can use much more memory, that is what I want.

Comment: which php version you are using? I would suggest use PHP 7.2 it will save lot of memory in array operations. Make sure you are doing garbage collection.

Comment: I am using 7.3, "garbage collection" I am probably not doing. Do you have any good links to read?

Comment: What is the error message you get when running the script? Another thing, try running `ini_get` and check the return value of `ini_set` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790808/how-to-get-the-real-memory-limit-in-a-php-script)

Comment: Tip: check out [generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) - _a generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount of processing time to generate_.

Comment: I had echo ini_get('memory_limit'); in my script, and if I set -1 I get -1, if I set 8192M I get 8192M, but still it crashed on 512 MB.

I am getting the Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxxxxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxx bytes)

I will read more about generators, thank you.

Comment: Those xxxxx bytes willl be useful in determining where the problem may be, any reason your redacted them?

Comment: Make sure you `ini_set` calls are not returning false - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php#refsect1-function.ini-set-returnvalues. Also, PHP uses different _ini_ files depending on the context it is running in (web Vs. CLI) and may also _include_ other _ini_ files which overwrite the one you think you're working with. Finally, I have to respectfully disagree with you that _The script is not the problem_. It certainly is the problem as shown by people's suggestions to use _generators_ which help to reduce memory consumption. Your script needs to be designed more efficiently.

Comment: I will test the feedback given. I also was thinking do be lazy and divide the arrays from start, then the script will not run out of memory.

I am also sure the script can be optimized, but I want to find out why I can not use the whole memory, maybe same problem is affecting the web directory of the server (even if it says it is using more everywhere).

Comment: Is the array basically a list of sales grabbed from the database, which is looped through and for each sale the stock table gets updated with the number sold deducted from the number in stock?

Comment: The script is storing data from a CSV file data into an array and is looping thru.

Comment: I edited the script creating the csv file, instead it now created 3 files. And three loopes in three different jobs.
Then I reach a maximum of 215 mb used and I can loop everything.

Problem solved. Sorry for cheating :)

Thank you all for the help and inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the memory limit on the command line, e.g.

```
php -d memory_limit=8191M <yourscript>.php
```

Comment: Same problem using this method